# Using sed to insert TABs

Tags: insert, tabs, sed, command, using

I use this command:

```
sed -i "10 i \t\t\ttime.sleep(0.1) " /home/test_file
```

to insert at line 10 a line like: `<TAB><TAB><TAB>sleep(0.1)`

But I got

```
t<TAB><TAB>sleep(0.1)...
```

Can you tell me how to get this result?
thanks

**PS. I use this command in an executable bash script.**

Comment: If darklion solved your problem, please accept their answer by clicking the hollow checkmark that appears in the left-hand margin. It will turn green to indicate that his answer was the most helpful in solving your problem. He (and you) will also be rewarded with some reputation points. It's not customary on Stack Overflow to edit the title to indicate the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe the problem is with competition between the way that the shell and sed are expanding the meta-characters. I've tried tripling the first backslash character and that seems to work for me:

```
sed -i "i \\\t\t\ttime.sleep(0.1) " tmp.tmp
```

Comment: Why have you posted two different answers? Apparently you already know that you can edit an existing answer, as you edited the one you posted before this one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like '\t' means a TAB on my host(ubuntu18.04). Below is my command line when i want to insert a new line beginning with TAB at the line 50 inside the *.json files.

> sed -i '50 i \t"opetin": true,' *.json