# How to determine which '\' is causing error?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, sed

I'm working with a Makefile with a target that's missing a recipe, and its causing a `make` to fail. I'm trying to patch a Makefile using `sed` in a bash script, and `sed` is failing claiming problems around a `\`. The script provides the recipe to download, untar, patch and build the sources.

The idea is to see if a recipe is present for `lldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a`, and add it at a particular location if its not found. So the recipe needs to be added with a leading tab and a trailing slash.

When the following executes:

```
# Determine if Apple
IS_DARWIN=`uname -s | egrep -i -c "Darwin"`
if [ $IS_DARWIN -ne 0 ]; then
  OTHER_OPTIONS=" --enable-libcpp"
fi

# Fix LLDB on OS X
if [ $IS_DARWIN -ne 0 ]; then
  cp Missing-Makefile llvm/tools/lldb/source/Plugins/SystemRuntime/MacOSX/Makefile
  chmod a+x llvm/tools/lldb/source/Plugins/SystemRuntime/MacOSX/Makefile

  COUNT=`cat llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile | egrep -i -c lldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX`
  echo *****COUNT: $COUNT*****

  if [ $COUNT -eq 0 ]; then
    sed -i '' "97i \tlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\" llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
  fi
fi
```

The snippet outputs the following error:

```
*****COUNT: 0*****
sed: 1: "97i \tlldbPluginSystemR ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command
```

***Note Well***: I am on OS X, and that means `sed` is not BSD `sed`, and its not Linux `sed`. OS X is its own world.

I'm having trouble zeroing in on the exact problem. I've tried adding three slashes to the tab per [Using sed to insert TABs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5190966/using-sed-to-insert-tabs), but that causes a similar error with two slashes. I also tried Nunk's suggestion of 2 slashes with no joy. It appears guessing at a problem is not the best approach.

The best I can tell, there is no verbose mode or other ways to get detailed information from `sed` on OS X.

**QUESTION**: How do I determine which `\` is causing the problem? Is it even possible to determine the problem slash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do in fact need an actual literal newline.

I often use the `cat` debugger :-) or sometimes a more advanced `vis` version  (e.g., `vis -w` does the trick on MacOS) to see what the input looks like, but in this case you need to inspect arguments rather than stdin, which makes it trickier.  Fortunately `echo "$@" | vis ...` is sufficient here:

```
  sed -i '' '97i\ 
TABCHARlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\ 
' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
```

becomes:

```
echo '97i\ 
TABCHARlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\ 
' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile | vis -w
```

which, fed to an `sh` (plain old sh, don't really need bash here) instance, gives me:

```
sh-3.2$ echo '97i\ 
> TABCHARlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\ 
> ' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile | vis -w
97i\\\040\^JTABCHARlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a\040\\\040\^J\040llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile\^Jsh-3.2$
```

which is not *very* readable, but does show that the backslash newline here had a space after it (that's the `\040` shoved in between the `\\` and `\^J`).  Removing it would make `sed` be OK with this, as long as that's actually what gets through.

Given a modern shell, you can encode stuff readably using `$'...'`:

```
sh-3.2$ echo $'magic: i\\\n\tstuff' | vis -w
magic:\040i\\\^J\^Istuff\^Jsh-3.2$
```

(remember, literal backslash is encoded in `vis` output as `\\`, literal newline is `\^J`, and literal tab is `\^I`).

Remember also that `echo` adds a newline, and `sed` does not, so you probably want something more like:

```
sed -i '' $'97i\\\n\tnew indented line inserted\n' Makefile
```

here.

Comment: One last question for this method. Where do I find a table of output like `\^J` and what it means?

Comment: `man vis` gives you section 1 (or me anyway, on ancient MacOS) and a reference to `vis(3)`; `man 3 vis` describes the encoding.  I was the one who convinced Bostic that there should be a vis(3) library routine and it should provide completely invertible encodings... the ones we came up with are a bit klunky but serviceable, anyway.  HTTP style was a later addition, not sure who put that in.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to escape the first backslash. Try:

```
sed '97i \\tlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
```

It works for me, using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Comment: Thanks Nunks. Unfortunately, I get the same error. Is there a way to actually determine the problem rather than guessing at the solution? Guessing is what I've been doing, and it wastes a lot of my time. I'd like to improve my methods.

Answer (score 0):

The man page for sed (on OSX) says:

```
[1addr]i\  
text        Write text to the standard output.
```

So the first thing to do is add the newline after a backslash following the `97i` then it seems that the `\t` for the TAB character is problematic so I would replace it with a placeholder (like `TABCHAR`) and substitute a real tab for that at the end.

Resulting in something like:

```
if [ $COUNT -eq 0 ]; then
  sed -i '' '97i\ 
TABCHARlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\ 
' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
  sed -i '' 's/TABCHAR/     /' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
fi
```

(the whitespace being substituted for `TABCHAR` in the second `sed` is a literal tab character)

Note that you probably can't successfully copy and paste this code, the newlines and backslashes are crucial and may get messed up.

Comment: Thanks Perry. I tried the `97i\\`, but it resulted in the same error. Is it possible to determine which slash is causing the problem? That's really what I am interested in knowing.

Comment: Nuts ... the site's code formatting messed up my post in which newlines were critically important.  Let me fix that.  To answer your question, all I did was read the manual to get the correct syntax for the `i` command which told me exactly what `sed` meant by `extra characters after \ at the end of i command`.

Comment: That was probably me on the formatting edit. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you are still getting the same error then the line with the `i` command does not end with a backslash and newline ... that is what the error message is saying, there is some character (even whitespace) after the backslash and before the newline that terminates the line.  The error message explicitly tells you which backslash it is referring to, the one `at the end of i command`.

Comment: *"error message explicitly tells you which backslash it is referring to, the one at the end of i command"* - I tried turning knobs on it too. In the trailing position, I tried adding double, triple and quad slashes. So I'm not sure if that's the one either. The error message sucks because its too vague. It needs to tell the position of the problem slash because guessing does not work. (I've even stopped using the command because the error message is so useless. I'm not trying to guess any longer).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using single, rather than double quotes around the command and changing it to:

```
sed -i '' '97i\    tlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
               ^ literal tab character
```

Note that the `i\` command requires its own backslash `\`. If you want to use the `\t` escape sequence to represent a tab character, you need to use extended mode `-E` as well:

```
sed -E -i '' '97i\\tlldbPluginSystemRuntimeMacOSX.a \\' llvm/tools/lldb/lib/Makefile
```

Comment: Thnks Tom. Believe it or not, I tried `97i\ ` with a tab literal. I got the same result. I'm really interested in determining *which* slash `sed` claims is offending. Its been a recurring problem for me on OS X.

Comment: That's strange, I can't reproduce the problem even when I use the `--posix` switch. It works as long as I use single rather than double quotes.